# How to get placeholder image in a custom collection on the home page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I want to get product's placeholder image in customs collection when products image is not set in admin side. I have set placeholder image in admin site.

```
<?php
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()                    
->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->load();
->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection); 


?>

<?php foreach ($collection as $_product){ ?>
<div class="pro-img">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(); ?>">
            </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: have you set placeholder image in admin side under system configuration? Can you share your image display code in question?

Comment: @AbdulI have attached code please check it and i have set placeholder image in admin side and it's showing on the product page.

Comment: Pls check my ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$image = $_product->getImage(); 
if ($image == NULL) 
{
    $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product/placeholder/default/no-image.jpg';
} 
else 
{
    $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$_product->getImage();
}
?>
<div class="pro-img">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code

**From:**

```
<div class="pro-img">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$_product->getImage(); ?>">
    </a>
</div>
```

**To**

```
<div class="pro-img">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**OR**

```
<div class="pro-img">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" />
    </a>
</div>
```